# Change ImageView after choosing photo from Gallery

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to change my imageview when its on click and then choose image from gallery then change it. But I don't think its working since when I tried running my project, it just crashes out of the app.

**Navigation Drawer**

[image]

**ActivityResult**

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                // Handle the returned Uri
            }
        });
```

**ImageView**

```
    profileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilepic);

    profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mGetContent.launch("image/*");
        }
    });
```

p.s. The ImageView is inside my navigation drawer. what I wanted to do is that whenever I click or press the ImageView which is the Hamburger Icon, it will redirect to gallery to choose image and then change it once the user chose one.

**MapsActivity.java**

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
OnMapReadyCallback,
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
LocationListener{

```
private static final String TAG = "";
private DrawerLayout drawer;
LatLng carWash1 = new LatLng(6.106535, 125.187230);
LatLng carWash2 = new LatLng(6.106123, 125.189280);

private ArrayList<LatLng> locationArrayList;

private ImageView profileImage;
final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private ActivityMapsBinding binding;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private Location recentLocation;
private Marker currentMark;
private static final int Request_User_Location = 1234;

private List<Polyline> polylines = null;

protected LatLng start = null;
protected LatLng end = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkUserLocationPermission();
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    locationArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    locationArrayList.add(carWash1);
    locationArrayList.add(carWash2);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */


public boolean checkUserLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_User_Location);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_User_Location);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Request_User_Location:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (googleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
    }
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < locationArrayList.size(); i++) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locationArrayList.get(0)).title("Purok 5 Carwashan").icon(BitMapFromVector(getApplication(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_airplanemode_active_24)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locationArrayList.get(1)).title("Stratford Carwashan").icon(BitMapFromVector(getApplication(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_airplanemode_active_24)));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locationArrayList.get(i), 15));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(locationArrayList.get(i)));
    }

    boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.style_json)));

    if (!success) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
    }
}

private BitmapDescriptor BitMapFromVector(Context context, int vectorResId) {
    // below line is use to generate a drawable.
    Drawable vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId);

    // below line is use to set bounds to our vector drawable.
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

    // below line is use to create a bitmap for our
    // drawable which we have added.
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // below line is use to add bitmap in our canvas.
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    // below line is use to draw our
    // vector drawable in canvas.
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);

    // after generating our bitmap we are returning our bitmap.
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
    recentLocation = location;

    if (currentMark != null) {
        currentMark.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Location!");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

    currentMark = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(12));

    if (googleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1100);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1100);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}